# retain data in form even after submitting or error in validation

Tags: python, forms, validation, pyramid, jinja2

I am currently into python and jinja2 right now. 
Is there a way to retain the data in the form(with validation) even after submitting it without using session? 
Because in my case, I have to manipulate it in my template(view) a couple of times. And even in my controller part. Could anyone teach a more easy way.

Here is what I do:

```
<input name="address" type="text" value="{% if form.data != '' and form.data and form and form != '' %}{% if form.data.address%}{{form.data.address}}{% else %}{{address}}{% endif %}{% elif form.data != '' and not form.data and form and form != ''  %}{{address}}{% else %}{{address}}{% endif %}" disabled/>
```

I validate through form.encode, so it validate in views(controller).

I know that it is kinda long. But I was able to retain the data, even my form was not validated. But it is a wrong way. Hope someone could teach me a more easy short way. Imagine the above code being written for a several textbox. It will be a hard time.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Are you using raw WSGI, or are you using some Python web framework with Jinja2? (And if a framework, which one)?

Comment: I am using python pyramid as framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can uses a hidden fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="address" value="{{form.data.address}}" />
```

Anyway, review the value condition, is redundant:

```
{% set value = '' %}
{% if form.data != '' and form.data and form and form != '' %}
    {% if form.data.address %}
        {% set value = form.data.address %}
    {% else %}
        {% set value = address %}
    {% endif %}
{% elif form.data != '' and not form.data and form and form != ''  %}
    {% set value = address %}
{% else %}
    {% set value = address %}
{% endif %}
```